# R: Faster version of "%in%"?

Tags: r

I have a large program that (alas) extensively uses the %in% operator. As our data grows in size, the program is running slowly -- and the problem appears to be the %in% operator. Below are some details of the problem.

I have a list of badwords, and I'd like to match an input list to the badwords.

```
input.words=c("hi","sample","badword")
bad.words=c("badword","badword2","badword3")

flag=which(input.words %in% bad.words)
# Do something with the flagged inputs ...
```

The input words (and bad words) are starting to become quite large, despite initially being small. The program is getting slower around %in%.

Is there a faster implementation of this operator? Or any other way to accomplish the same goal in parallel or more quickly? Many thanks in advance. Help!

Comment: `which` is faster than `%in%`.

Comment: Thanks! I updated the question to clarify the exact code. Note that I'm already using which, but maybe in an inefficient way.

Answer (score 2):

The `data.table` package provides `%chin%` which is described as "a fast version of `%in%` for character vectors" - seems like it's exactly what you are looking for.

The help page shows a benchmark on 100k records where `%in%` takes 4.5 seconds and `%chin%` takes 1.7 seconds - so you should expect at least a 2x speedup.

If you can get away with `match` rather than `%in%`, they also have a `chmatch` function which is a faster version of `match` for character vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use base function `match` to extract those indices in the `input.words` that exist in `bad.words` like this:

```
> match(input.words, bad.words)    # match returns NA when there is no match 
[1] NA NA  1

# So we use is.na to return only those for which there are a match in the second vector
input.words[!is.na(match(input.words, bad.words))]
[1] "badword"
```

I hope this works.

Comment: If you look at the source code for `%in%`, this is basically rewriting `%in%` using `!is.na()` instead of `> 0` and setting the argument `nomatch = 0L`.

Comment: Yes that's true. Thank you for your recommendation from `data.table` package. It was really helpful.